# java.net sourceCode reader skipping lines

Tags: java

This code is ment to download the source code of an html file
but it skips some of the lines why would that happen?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class downloadSource {
  private URL url;
  private URLConnection con;

  // Construct the object with a new URL Object resource
  downloadSource(String url) {
    try {
      this.url = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  // Returns an object instance 
  public BufferedReader SourceCodeStream() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.url.openStream()));
  }


  public void returnSource() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // FIX ENTRIE SOURCE CODE IS NOT BEING DWLOADED

    // Instinate a new object by assigning it the returned object from
    // the invoked SourceCodeStream method.

    BufferedReader s = this.SourceCodeStream();     
    if(s.ready()) { 
      String sourceCodeLine = s.readLine();
      Vector<String> linesOfSource = new Vector();
      while(sourceCodeLine != null) {
        sourceCodeLine = s.readLine();
        linesOfSource.add(s.readLine());            
      }

      Iterator lin = linesOfSource.iterator();
      while(lin.hasNext()) {
      }
    }
  }         
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This reads two lines per iteration:

```
while(sourceCodeLine != null) {
      sourceCodeLine = s.readLine();

      linesOfSource.add(s.readLine());

  }
```

Should be:

```
while(sourceCodeLine != null) {
      linesOfSource.add(sourceCodeLine);
      sourceCodeLine = s.readLine();
  }
```

This second loop adds the first line to `linesOfSource` that was also skipped:

```
String sourceCodeLine = s.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is missing the first line, and every other line, because you start out with this:

```
String sourceCodeLine = s.readLine();
```

Then never do anything with `sourceCodeLine` before it is assigned again.  You have another similar problem within your loop.

Instead, you could do something like this:

```
String sourceCodeLine;
Vector<String> linesOfSource = new Vector();

while((sourceCodeLine = s.readLine()) != null) {
    linesOfSource.add(sourceCodeLine);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `readLine()` it reads a new line, so you need to save the information it returns every time `readLine()` is executed, but you are not doing that. Try something like this instead:

```
while((tmp = s.readLine()) != null){
    linesOfSource.add(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
 while(sourceCodeLine != null) {
        sourceCodeLine = s.readLine();

        linesOfSource.add(s.readLine());

    }
```

You read twice the line and add only one to the `linesofSource`.

This will solve the problem.

```
while(sourceCodeLine != null) {    
        linesOfSource.add(sourceCodeLine); // We add line to list
        sourceCodeLine = s.readLine(); // We read another line
    }
```